# GWT Development mode - Unable to load module in Chrome

Tags: java, gwt, development-mode

I'm trying to load my app in development mode using Chrome v. 20.0 on my local ip 127.0.0.1.
The app fails to load, and the following is displayed:

1. message:
   "GWT Code Server Disconnected
   Most likely, you closed GWT Development Mode. Or, you might have lost network connectivity. To fix this, try restarting GWT Development Mode and REFRESH this page."
2. on top of the previous message (overlaid): 
   "Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997
   Follow the underlying troubleshooting instructions"

This started to happen about 6-9 months ago and after 1 or 2 page refresh, the module loaded correctly. Now, i cannot load my app in dev-mode at all using Chrome. (in firefox 
everything is ok).
I'm using GWT 2.4

UPDATE:

Those errors are not accompanied by any code stack trace output. Usually, if I changed the address form 127.0.0.1 to localhost, the module loaded, but this doesn't work any more...

Comment: Check if your GWT development plugin is still working

Comment: It says it is enabled, but when i get the errors above, the GWT  icon is greyed...

Comment: i did... didn't work... maybe i should uninstall it, clear all browser data and then reinstall

Comment: No luck with the uninstall, clear data, reinstall... I even cleared all previous gwt output.

Comment: Regarding my first comment: although I get those errors, the GWT plugin icon is actually red, not grey. Also: no code stack trace is displayed.

Comment: Also tried to re-install Chrome... no luck here either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM

This page is supposed to be displayed in an iframe below the message (hence the message "underlying instructions", but Google has changed some server code on `code.google.com` and they now prohibit display within iframes, which is why it actually doesn't display.

FYI, the issue has been reported on GWT's issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7301

Comment: Regarding troubleshooting: the GWT plugin/extension icon is red, not grey; i'm trying to run my app on local machine; i am using GPE and no  errors are displayed in the Development mode panel in Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Deleting / reinstalling the plugin did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check Automatically select an unused port of GWT from Run configuration.
My similar problem solved by this

Comment: Did this, got exactly the same errors. I accessed my app from both browsers (Chrome, Firefox) on the new port given automatically - on firefox worked, on chrome failed :(

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in chrome by:

- go to chrome://extensions/
- locate GWT Developer Plugin
- uncheck the Enabled box
- check the Enabled box

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be caused by improper gwt plugin setup. Go to your gwt developer plugin options (red toolbox right upper conner) in chrome and add your web and code server addresses. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing "localhost" as webserver and code server made it work for me (although 127.0.0.1 was specified for both in the browser)